# get output of numpy loadtxt as a single array rather than multiple array

Tags: arrays, numpy, load

I have a CSV file:

```
8.84,17.22,13.22,3.84  
3.99,11.73,19.66,1.27
```

```
Def jo(x):
    data=np.loadtxt(x,delimiter=',')
    Return data
Print(jo('data.csv')
```

The code returns:

```
[ [8.84 17.22 13.22 3.84]  
 [3.99 11.73 19.66 1.27] ]
```

But I want all these elements in a single array, because I want to find their `mean` and `median`.
How to combine these 2 arrays into 1 ?

Comment: That is 1 array.  And can take mean and median.  look at their docs.

Answer (score 0):

use [`numpy.rehshape`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html)

```py
# data: data is your array
>>> data.reshape(-1)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
In [245]: txt="""8.84,17.22,13.22,3.84   
     ...: 3.99,11.73,19.66,1.27"""                                                               
In [246]: data = np.loadtxt(txt.splitlines(), delimiter=',')                                     
In [247]: data                                                                                   
Out[247]: 
array([[ 8.84, 17.22, 13.22,  3.84],
       [ 3.99, 11.73, 19.66,  1.27]])
In [248]: data.shape                                                                             
Out[248]: (2, 4)
```

That is one array, just 2d.

There are various ways of turning that into a 1d array:

```
In [259]: arr = data.ravel()                                                                     
In [260]: arr                                                                                    
Out[260]: array([ 8.84, 17.22, 13.22,  3.84,  3.99, 11.73, 19.66,  1.27])
```

But there's no need to do that.  `mean` (and `median`) without axis parameter acts on the raveled array.  Check the docs:

```
In [261]: np.mean(data)                                                                          
Out[261]: 9.971250000000001
In [262]: np.mean(arr)                                                                           
Out[262]: 9.971250000000001
```